# NET MAUI ,,There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'ios-arm64',,

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, maui

I am using VS 2022, NET 7.
I am learning NET MAUI.

I created a project where the REST API project and the MAUI projects are in the same solution, so I can share the models between them.

If I put my view models in MAUI project everything works fine, but If I reference the .NET Class library where my models are, I get always the following error on build:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NETSDK1082  There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'ios-arm64'.
```

I can provide any code snippet if it helps.

thnx

UPDATE (MAUI csproj file):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net7.0-android;net7.0-maccatalyst;net7.0-ios15.0</TargetFrameworks>
        <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
        <!-- Uncomment to also build the tizen app. You will need to install tizen by following this: https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.NET -->
        <!-- <TargetFrameworks>$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-tizen</TargetFrameworks> -->
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <RootNamespace>Mobile.UI</RootNamespace>
        <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
        <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>

        <!-- Display name -->
        <ApplicationTitle>Mobile.UI</ApplicationTitle>

        <!-- App Identifier -->
        <ApplicationId>com.companyname.mobile.ui</ApplicationId>
        <ApplicationIdGuid>153a2ae5-5e5c-43b1-88e0-30367a6e48f1</ApplicationIdGuid>

        <!-- Versions -->
        <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>

        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">11.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">13.1</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'tizen'">6.5</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- App Icon -->
        <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" Color="#512BD4" />

        <!-- Splash Screen -->
        <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />

        <!-- Images -->
        <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
        <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.svg" BaseSize="168,208" />

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

        <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
        <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <None Remove="Platforms\Android\Resources\xml\network_security_config.xml" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" Version="2.2.5" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="7.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" Version="7.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="7.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="7.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="7.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="7.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.2.8" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <None Update="Resources\Raw\Mobile.UI.Development.json">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </None>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <MauiAsset Update="Resources\Raw\Mobile.UI.Development.json">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </MauiAsset>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <MauiXaml Update="Components\PlayerListComponent.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      </MauiXaml>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <Folder Include="Pages\" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\Backend.Database\Backend.Database.csproj" />
      <ProjectReference Include="..\Backend.Models\Backend.Models.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ProjectExtensions><VisualStudio><UserProperties XamarinHotReloadDebuggerTimeoutExceptionMobileUIHideInfoBar="True" /></VisualStudio></ProjectExtensions>

</Project>
```

REST API csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="data.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations" Version="6.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Caching" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="7.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Z.EntityFramework.Extensions.EFCore" Version="7.18.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore" Version="7.18.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Controllers\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="data.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Backend.Middleware\Backend.Middleware.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Backend.Services\Backend.Services.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Backend.Validation\Backend.Validation.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

UPDATE: Models.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup> 
 
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Backend.Database\Backend.Database.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Please show csproj files for projects.

Comment: @LukaszSzczygielek updatet. Do you need any other csproj file?

Comment: Please also add a csproj for the REST API.

Comment: @LukaszSzczygielek I added, but I not see the connection, because the MAUI app doesent has reference on REST API?!

Comment: **1)** Are you saying that it builds and runs if viewmodels are part of Maui project, but if you move viewmodels to a separate project, it gives that error? **2)** **Are you running on iOS?** If not, remove `ios` and `maccatlyst` from `TargetFrameworks`. **3)**Add .csproj for the viewmodels project.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Exactly that was I am saying. And I removed all nuget packages that doesn't needed in Models class library. I updated.

Comment: Does the build error happen during build of viewmodels project? Or does it happen later, when main project builds? Also, if you remove REST API project (so only two projects in solution), does it still happen?

Comment: I figured out yesterday. Matalama was cousing the trouple. Right now Metalama and MAUI are not supporting each other. Removing Metamala.Framweork package solved all the errors.

Comment: please @Wasyster i am facing the same issue but am not using Metamala

Comment: I recreated my whole project, that was the way I figured out.
Perhaps if you can share a git repo.